# Output the result of a variable

Tags: shell, variable, output

I have an if statement and I want in one case to add one to a variable v and in the other case to a variable inv.
I did the following
`v=$((v + 1))` and `inv=$((inv + 1))`
I want to outputs the results of this so i did this

```
echo "The number of valid is "$v" and the number of invalid is "$inv"."
```

but when i run the program it's not working? how do i output the result of the equation?

Comment: Please define "not working" here. (You can [edit])

Comment: Provide sample code in your question, including the output.

Comment: What's the error that you get? From the information you have provided, everything seems to work fine. So you'll have to give more specific details on the error and the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1):

For starters you should quote your variables (ie place them inside `"..."`). So your output statement should read thus:

```
echo "The number of valid is $v and the number of invalid is $inv."
```

I'll update my answer if you find you need to update your question.